# Chef recipe to check redhat subscription manager status and send email notification if the status is inactive or chef run fails

Tags: linux, chef-infra

I am new to chef and would like to get a detailed answer for this please.
The scenario is like:

I want to check redhat subscription manager status on client nodes. If the status is active/current, then it patches the server else it sends email notification when the chef run fails or the redhat subscription status is inactive/unknown.

Basically I would run below recipe to patch a server:

```
execute 'Server_patching' do
  command ' yum update'
end
```

But this is only possible if the subscription manager is active or the recipe runs successfully.

Comment: How do you plan to check the subscription status?

Comment: I would use command " subscription-manager status" to check the subscription status. Thanks